# Using Markdown syntax inside justified paragraph

Tags: markdown

I am trying to use Markdown syntax to include some words in bold character inside a justified paragraph. I am trying the code below but it doesn't work.

```
<p align="justify"> 
 Trying to use **bold characters** inside justified paragraph.
</p>
```

This is the result I get:

> Trying to use **bold characters** inside
>   justified paragraph.

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use HTML inside your `<p>` [since it's a block-level element](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style `*emphasis*` inside an HTML block.

For example:

```
<p align="justify"> 
 Trying to use <strong>bold characters</strong> inside justified paragraph.
</p>
```